# Single / Compile time evaluation of custom type as argument (Implicit constexpr?)

Tags: c++, optimization, parameters, parameter-passing, constexpr

Given the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myFunction(Color(1.f, 1.f, 0.f));
}
```

The constructor of Color would be called 100 times, although it always evaluates to the same thing every time and myFunction does not create a copy (utilizing `const Color&`).

I have already taken the necessary steps to design Color to be constexpr friendly:

```
class Color {
public:
    constexpr Color(float r, float g, float b, float a = 1.f) : red(r), green(g), blue(b), alpha(a) {
        if (r > 1.f) { throw std::runtime_exception("..."); }
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

But that does not seem to achieve what I would like it to achieve.

Assuming I have no control over `myFunction`, is there some sort of way that Color could be designed in order to evaluate the object a single time, possibly at compile time and then simply have it be passed to the function every time?
Basically the automatic conversion of the code above to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    constexpr Color myColor(1.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    myFunction(myColor);
}
```

The above code works, and even detects invalid input at compile time!

Of note could be that detecting whether this optimization is actually already performed has proven quite hard for me, as adding measures to detect it could very well prevent it from being optimized away. Maybe the compiler will actually optimize it in a majority of cases, who knows? (Well, I hope someone here does.) But even then, at least the compile time error detection doesn't appear to be present.

I am using C++17 but of course I'm happy to hear solutions utilizing newer language features as well!

Is there anything more I can do or am I just ultimately at the mercy of the compiler here?

Comment: What is the parameter to `myFunction` declared as?

Comment: `const Color&` to avoid copies

Comment: Then that's probably the most you can do, if the compiler is unwilling to optimize it any further. Declaring a `static const` instance of this object, and passing that, would be the most extreme solution, then.

Comment: Would that actually be preferable to `constexpr` in this case? Either way, yeah, I feel like that would just be way too tedious. Thank you very much!

Comment: It occurs to me that declaring `Color` outside of the `for` loop should do the trick. That's too obvious. Too bad you don't have "full control".

Comment: While `static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<Color>);` can't *guarantee* that the compiler will optimize things out, it will make it as likely as possible.

Comment: Also, be wary of testing for "calling the copy constructor". Most attempts to check this by any means other than reading the resulting assembly will change the behaviour and make it look like there's overhead when there might very well not be any.

Comment: Move the loop inside `myFunction`  It's strange to pass the same parameter into the same function 100 times.  eg `myFunction(myColor, 100);`

Comment: The loop simply serves to illustrate my problem better, in practice it's an event loop I'm dealing with.